# Psycopg2 Operational Error: could not connect to server : No such file or directory

Tags: python, postgresql, shell, psycopg2

Trying to connect to postgresql within the python shell but I am running into some problems.

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux.  I tried changing the port to 5433 instead of 5432.  And tried setting the host="/tmp/".  Neither of these things worked.

I tried running this.

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The database 'postgres' appears in the list of databases:

```
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

I expected to be able to create tables within the postgres database but I cannot seem to get around this error.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow! Have you tried connecting via the command-line with your specified arguments/user/pwd?

Answer (score 6):

did you try to add host and password and port in psycopg2.connect() like : `conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres" , password="your_db_user_password" , host="127.0.0.1")` ?